# Archive navigation on Wordpress - Solution with .htaccess redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with the navigation of my category archive (Wordpress). My website structure is **example.com/blabla-news/post-name/**. When I go into my category archive and want to click on page 2, it's showing me a 404 Error page i.e **example.com/blabla-news/page/2** is a 404 Error page.

I've found the solution for that. To open the 2nd page of my archive I will need to add the word category i.e **example.com/*CATEGORY*/blabla-news/page/2**.

I've found a solution to solve that but only for 1 archive category i.e the following code is solving the problem for 1 category archive.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^news/page/([^/]+)?$ category/news/page/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/page/(.*)$  category/news/page/$1 [L,NC,R=302]`

I have ~200 Categories, so I want to fix this problem with code that will affect all categories.

Comment: Why your original URL does not have /category/ in the URL already, as that is default wp behaviour, are you using Yoast, or some other plugn and had set to remove /category/ , in that case you may turn that off and /category will be in all links by wp by default.

Comment: If you using Yoast look in Yoast SEO -> Advanced Settings page, then second tab is Permalinks

Comment: Thank you @Mohsin, you solved my problem!

Comment: Great! I post it as an answer for reference you may make it resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WordPress permalinks have by standard practice that /category/ part in category archive url already. However some people prefer to remove that part and use custom code or plugins.

One example is Yoast plugin which is in your case, looks like you have turned on the option which removes "/category" url part which is breaking pagination on category pages also. To have the /category slug back in the URL. You may turn it off in Yoast by going to "Yoast SEO -> Advanced Settings page, then second tab is Permalinks", first option is which deals with it says:

> **Change URLs** Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL.

You may turn this off to restore /category part in the URLs.